# Drawing between 2 images in 1 JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, draw

I want to draw the lines between 2 `JScrollPanes` (first scroll pane on the left side, second on the right). These `JScrollPanes` contain images. I want to draw lines between these 2 images (use some layers, use some trick etc.). I tried do it different ways, but i failed. Is it possible? (if not, i will have to make 2 images in one `JScrollPane` and it won't be nice).

**EDIT**

I want to draw between 2 images - throught components - get some points from images and draw lines between them. I apologize for poorly formulated question.

Comment: I believe what you'll need to do is paint on the Glass Pane. I'll edit my answer shortly to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, I believe you'll need to make use of the `Glass Pane`. The `Glass Pane` sits on top of everything in the `JRootPane` and fills the entire view. This particular position allows two distinct capabilities:

- Intercepting mouse and keyboard events
- **Drawing over the entire user interface**

I believe your question is addressed by the second capability. The following is an example implementation, which you can later tailor to meet your own needs. Note that I've left out a lot of detail with regard to `Glass Pane` that you'll need to research on your own.

**CODE**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GlassPaneDemo {
        private static BufferedImage bi;

        public static void main(String[] args){
            try {
                loadImages();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        createAndShowGUI();             
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }

        private static void loadImages() throws IOException{
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/person.png"));
        }

        private static void createAndShowGUI(){
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setGlassPane(new CustomGlassPane());
            frame.getContentPane().add(getButtonPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private static final JPanel getButtonPanel(){
            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                    Graphics gCopy = g.create();

                    gCopy.setColor(Color.BLUE.darker());
                    gCopy.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                    gCopy.dispose();
                }
            };

            final JLabel labelOne = new JLabel();
            labelOne.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
            final JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel();
            labelTwo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
            panel.add(labelOne);
            panel.add(labelTwo);

            return panel;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        private static class CustomGlassPane extends JComponent{
            private Point p1;
            private Point p2;
            private boolean lineDrawn;

            public CustomGlassPane(){
                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                        if(p1 == null || lineDrawn){
                            if(lineDrawn){
                                p1 = null;
                                p2 = null;
                                lineDrawn = false;
                            }
                            p1 = e.getPoint();
                        }else{
                            p2 = e.getPoint();
                            repaint(); // not optimal
                            lineDrawn = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Block all other input events
                addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){});
                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){});
                addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){
                        requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                });
                setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                if(p1 != null && p2 != null){
                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                    g2.setRenderingHint(
                            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2.drawLine((int)p1.getX(), (int)p1.getY(), (int)p2.getX(), (int)p2.getY());

                    g2.dispose();
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EXPLANATION**

In this example, I clicked two arbitrary points within each `JLabel`, and then drew a connecting line.

Comment: If this is really working... Then I learned something new today :D, I though that we should call `drawChilderen` or something like that in our overrided method. +1

Comment: Thanks, but this will works only for `Component`, respectively connect `Component`. I need draw lines through `JScrollPane`. I get some points from images and i want to connect them. This example doesn't work for that.

Comment: @Equo, Well, thanks for the clarification, but try to be more clear with your requirements beforehand!

Comment: @little bunny foo foo, thanks, now it seems that it works. I was thinking about this, before few hours, when i found it on oracle tutorials page, but i haven´t time to try it.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to draw outside the frame, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This should be very possible.  You will need to create a custom component that is aware of both vertical ScrollBars.  It should add itself as an `AdjustmentListener` to each scroll bar in order to detect changes and repaint the lines between the two.

See:
[addAdjustmentListener method in the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#addAdjustmentListener%28java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this 
http://java-sl.com/connector.html
as an example of such code.