# Drawing outside a component's bounds

Tags: java, swing, drawing, bounds, clip

I'm making a component (extending JComponent) which will have some decoration drawn over the top of it and partly outside its bounds.

I would like to know if there's a way of drawing outside the component using self-contained code (I don't want to have to do any drawing in the parent container, for example).

Comment: Try the setClip method of GRaphics. In my attempt it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no easy solution. One way to achieve this is to draw on the container's `GlassPane`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609888/drawing-between-2-images-in-1-jpanel/6610064#6610064). IMHO, I would just modify the `Graphics` object of the component to change the "apparent" bounds, which will enable you to draw stuff that's "outside the bounds" on the component itself.

Comment: You mean with setClip? I thought that could only be used to shrink the drawing area.

Comment: OK, I was wrong. The reason I've only just marked this as the answer is that I've just fixed a problem that I've been stuck on for hours which has a really simple solution: **If you don't repaint the parent container as well as the component, no rendering will show up on it.** Obvious, but not easy to spot because I was redrawing in mouse and component events, some of which repaint the container and some of which don't.

Comment: @Tharwen, Then you should answer your own question and mark that as the correct one. :D

Comment: No, your answer was the solution, but that bold part was just a thing that I thought would be helpful for anyone reading this later.