# Can I draw outside the component boundaries in swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, border, swingx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing outside a component's bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970938/drawing-outside-a-components-bounds)

I'd like to make "good looking" interface using Swing (and SwingX) and i'm still struggling with creating nice shadows. I found that there is already a border do what i want (partially) in SwingX, [DropShadowBorder](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/border/DropShadowBorder.html).

I have also found [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2005/07/07/fast-or-good-drop-shadows/), the shadows are really nice but it works with images. But i'm sure you can make it works with `JComponent`. I have already modified the code to generate an empty `BufferedImage` with the size of the component (it only works for rectangular components but i don't really care) and create the shadow from this image.

The shadow generation works but my problem is that i can only render the shadow within the boundaries of the swing component but i have to render the shadow with an offset on both axis.

**Can i avoid this and render outside the component boundaries? For example, can i draw anything at (0, 100) in the paintComponent method of a component that have a size of (50, 50) ?**

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here is an example of what i'd like to avoid. The shadow exceed the size of the component of both axis (the component is not rendered to let you see the shadow).

[image]

**EDIT2**: i'm not sure if i was clear enough (if it's the case i'm sorry) so here graphical representation of what i want to do.

[image]

Comment: @CatalinaIsland already noted as duplicate and i have answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code may help you

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Panel2Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ShadeOptionsPanel shadeOptions = new ShadeOptionsPanel();
                ShadowSelector shadowSelector = new ShadowSelector(shadeOptions);
                //ComponentSource componentSource = new ComponentSource(shadeOptions);
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Rounded Concept Demo with Shadows");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(shadowSelector, "North");
                f.add(shadeOptions);
                //f.add(componentSource, "South");
                f.setSize(300, 200);
                f.setLocation(150, 150);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private Panel2Test() {
    }
}

class ShadeOptionsPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int PAD, DIA, BORDER;
    private Color colorIn, colorOut;
    private int xc, yc;
    private Ellipse2D eIn, eOut;
    private GradientPaint gradient;
    private CustomPaint customPaint;
    private Area arcBorder;
    private int width, height;
    private Point2D neOrigin, nwOrigin, swOrigin, seOrigin, neDiag, nwDiag, swDiag, seDiag;
    private final static int NORTHEAST = 0, NORTHWEST = 1, SOUTHWEST = 2, SOUTHEAST = 3;
    public int shadowVertex = 3;

    public ShadeOptionsPanel() {
        PAD = 25;
        DIA = 75;
        BORDER = 10;
        colorIn = Color.black;
        colorOut = getBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        g2.drawRoundRect(PAD, PAD, width - 2 * PAD, height - 2 * PAD, DIA, DIA);
        calculateArcOrigins();
        calculateCardinalDiagonals();
        drawVertexArc(g2, shadowVertex);
        switch (shadowVertex) {
            case NORTHEAST:
                drawNorthSide(g2);
                drawEastSide(g2);
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2; // draw northwest arc
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw southeast arc
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case NORTHWEST:
                drawNorthSide(g2);
                drawWestSide(g2);
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;// draw northeast arc
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2;// draw southwest arc
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case SOUTHWEST:
                drawWestSide(g2);
                drawSouthSide(g2);
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2; // draw northwest arc
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw the southeast arc
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case SOUTHEAST:
                drawEastSide(g2);
                drawSouthSide(g2);
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw northeast arc
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2;  // draw southwest arc
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = getInnerEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                eOut = getOuterEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
        }
    }

    private Ellipse2D getInnerEllipse(Point2D center, Point2D corner) {
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - DIA / 2,
                center.getY() - DIA / 2, DIA, DIA);
    }

    private Ellipse2D getOuterEllipse(Point2D center, Point2D corner) {
        int w = DIA, h = DIA;
        if (shadowVertex < 2) {
            if (center.getY() > corner.getY()) {
                h += 2 * BORDER;
            } else {
                w += 2 * BORDER;
            }
        } else if (center.getY() > corner.getY()) {
            w += 2 * BORDER;
        } else {
            h += 2 * BORDER;
        }
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - w / 2, center.getY() - h / 2, w, h);
    }

    private Area getArcArea(Ellipse2D e1, Ellipse2D e2, double start) {
        Arc2D arc1 = new Arc2D.Double(e1.getBounds2D(), start, 90.0, Arc2D.PIE);
        Arc2D arc2 = new Arc2D.Double(e2.getBounds2D(), start, 90.0, Arc2D.PIE);
        Area arc = new Area(arc2);
        arc.subtract(new Area(arc1));
        return arc;
    }

    private void drawNorthSide(Graphics2D g2) {
        gradient = new GradientPaint(width / 2, PAD - BORDER, colorOut,
                width / 2, PAD, colorIn);
        g2.setPaint(gradient);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, PAD - BORDER,
                width - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1, BORDER));
    }

    private void drawWestSide(Graphics2D g2) {
        gradient = new GradientPaint(PAD - BORDER, height / 2, colorOut,
                PAD, height / 2, colorIn);
        g2.setPaint(gradient);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, PAD + DIA / 2,
                BORDER, height - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1));
    }

    private void drawSouthSide(Graphics2D g2) {
        gradient = new GradientPaint(width / 2, height - PAD, colorIn,
                width / 2, height - PAD + BORDER, colorOut);
        g2.setPaint(gradient);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, height - PAD,
                width - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1, BORDER));
    }

    private void drawEastSide(Graphics2D g2) {
        gradient = new GradientPaint(width - PAD, height / 2, colorIn,
                width - PAD + BORDER, height / 2, colorOut);
        g2.setPaint(gradient);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(width - PAD, PAD + DIA / 2,
                BORDER, height - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1));
    }

    /**
     * Draws the central, full-shaded arc (opposite of the unshaded arc).
     */
    private void drawVertexArc(Graphics2D g2, int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case NORTHEAST:
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA, PAD, DIA, DIA);
                eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA - BORDER, PAD - BORDER,
                        DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case NORTHWEST:
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD, PAD, DIA, DIA);
                eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, PAD - BORDER,
                        DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case SOUTHWEST:
                xc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD, height - PAD - DIA, DIA, DIA);
                eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, height - PAD - DIA - BORDER,
                        DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
                break;
            case SOUTHEAST:
                xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;
                yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                        DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA, height - PAD - DIA, DIA, DIA);
                eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA - BORDER,
                        height - PAD - DIA - BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                g2.fill(arcBorder);
        }
    }

    private void calculateArcOrigins() {
        neOrigin = new Point2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA / 2, PAD + DIA / 2);
        nwOrigin = new Point2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, PAD + DIA / 2);
        swOrigin = new Point2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, height - PAD - DIA / 2);
        seOrigin = new Point2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA / 2, height - PAD - DIA / 2);
    }

    private void calculateCardinalDiagonals() {
        neDiag = new Point2D.Double(neOrigin.getX()
                + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45)) / 2,
                neOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(45)) / 2);
        nwDiag = new Point2D.Double(nwOrigin.getX()
                + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(135)) / 2,
                nwOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(135)) / 2);
        swDiag = new Point2D.Double(swOrigin.getX()
                + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(225)) / 2,
                swOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(225)) / 2);
        seDiag = new Point2D.Double(seOrigin.getX()
                + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(315)) / 2,
                seOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(315)) / 2);
    }

    public Dimension getInnerSize() {
        return new Dimension((int) nwOrigin.distance(neOrigin),
                (int) nwOrigin.distance(swOrigin));
    }
}

class ShadowSelector extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ShadeOptionsPanel soPanel;
    private String[] directions = {"northeast", "northwest", "southwest", "southeast"};

    public ShadowSelector(ShadeOptionsPanel sop) {
        soPanel = sop;

        final SpinnerListModel model = new SpinnerListModel(directions);
        model.setValue(directions[3]);
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, spinner.getPreferredSize().height));
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                String value = (String) model.getValue();
                soPanel.shadowVertex = model.getList().indexOf(value);
                soPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        add(new JLabel("shadow vertex", JLabel.RIGHT));
        add(spinner);
    }
}

class CustomPaint implements Paint {

    Point2D originP, radiusP;
    int radius, border;
    Color colorIn, colorOut;

    public CustomPaint(int x, int y, Point2D radiusP,
            int radius, int border,
            Color colorIn, Color colorOut) {
        originP = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        this.radiusP = radiusP;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.border = border;
        this.colorIn = colorIn;
        this.colorOut = colorOut;
    }

    @Override
    public PaintContext createContext(ColorModel cm, Rectangle deviceBounds, Rectangle2D userBounds, AffineTransform xform, RenderingHints hints) {
        Point2D xformOrigin = xform.transform(originP, null), xformRadius = xform.deltaTransform(radiusP, null);
        return new CustomPaintContext(xformOrigin, xformRadius, radius, border, colorIn, colorOut);
    }

    @Override
    public int getTransparency() {
        int alphaIn = colorIn.getAlpha();
        int alphaOut = colorOut.getAlpha();
        return (((alphaIn & alphaOut) == 0xff) ? OPAQUE : TRANSLUCENT);
    }
}

class CustomPaintContext implements PaintContext {

    Point2D originP, radiusP;
    Color colorIn, colorOut;
    int radius, border;

    public CustomPaintContext(Point2D originP, Point2D radiusP, int radius, int border, Color colorIn, Color colorOut) {
        this.originP = originP;
        this.radiusP = radiusP;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.border = border;
        this.colorIn = colorIn;
        this.colorOut = colorOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public ColorModel getColorModel() {
        return ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
    }

    @Override
    public Raster getRaster(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        WritableRaster raster = getColorModel().createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
        int[] data = new int[w * h * 4];
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                double distance = originP.distance(x + i, y + j);
                double r = radiusP.distance(radius, radius);
                double ratio = distance - r < 0 ? 0.0 : (distance - r) / border;
                if (ratio > 1.0) {
                    ratio = 1.0;
                }
                int base = (j * w + i) * 4;
                data[base + 0] = (int) (colorIn.getRed() + ratio * (colorOut.getRed() - colorIn.getRed()));
                data[base + 1] = (int) (colorIn.getGreen() + ratio * (colorOut.getGreen() - colorIn.getGreen()));
                data[base + 2] = (int) (colorIn.getBlue() + ratio * (colorOut.getBlue() - colorIn.getBlue()));
                data[base + 3] = (int) (colorIn.getAlpha() + ratio * (colorOut.getAlpha() - colorIn.getAlpha()));
            }
        }
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);
        return raster;
    }
}
```